# What is error in code for adding 3*3 matrix?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a[3][3] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
   int b[3][3] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
   int c[3][3];
   for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
   {
       for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
       {
           c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
           cout<<"Element of C"<<i<<j<<"is\t"<<c[i][j]<<endl;
       
       }
  
   
   }

       return 0;

}
```

In the above code i a am getting correct output till A22 but for above it is throwing me a
garbage value.

Comment: You need to learn about indices to arrays in C: indices start from ZERO, hence a three-item array has indices 0, 1 and 2, that is _less than_ three and not _less-or-equal_ three.

Answer (score 4):

You need to index your matrices starting from 0, not 1. So, you need to change you `for` loops to be like `for(int i=0;i<3;i++)`.

Answer (score 2):

- [Do not `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- Two-dimensional arrays should better be initialized with double parenthesis

  `int a[3][3] = {{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}};`

  `int b[3][3] = {{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}};`
- Array indices in C/C++ *start from 0*. Hence the loop should read

  `for(int i=0;i<3;i++)`

  and similar for the nested loop
- Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for C++.